# Is there a way to use a DataTemplate with a parameter?

Tags: wpf, gridview, binding, datatemplate, parameters

I need to dynamically add/remove GridView columns, each displaying information from a different element stored in a KeyedCollection (indexed with tn 'int'). The basic technique works, but requires an index, as follows:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="bid">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Width="60" DataContext="{Binding Elements}" Text="{Binding [546].PropName}" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

However, at run-time I need to add more of these, with different integer keys, at which point I'm not sure how to create new DataTemplates, each with a different binding index.

Constructing a new DataTemplate using the XamlParser seems quite ugly...

Any help?

Comment: Is the "PropName" a property of each object placed in the GridView?

Comment: No, each object placed in the GridView (actially in the ItemsSource of a ListView) has an 'Elements' property, which is a KeyedCollection containing objects, each with a PropName property

Comment: and where does the '546' come from? is it some kind of random for each object?

Comment: 546 is some key for the keyed collection. the collection will typically contains several objects with different keys, each one should have a corresponding column

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I seem to understand you need your objects to have some additional properties. Something like `Key` and `ValueFromKey`. This properties could look similar to this:

```
public int Key { get; set; }

public object ValueFromKey
{
   get { return this[Key]; }
}
```

Then at the moment you're adding the GridView columns you should set the Key property's value to the 'magic' number (like 546 from the example).

And your `DataTemplate` will look as simple as this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock 
        Width="60" 
        Text="{Binding ValueFromKey.PropName}" 
        TextAlignment="Center" 
        />
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem arises if you cannot change that class. Then you could probably consider wrapping it with your own class (kind of a ViewModel) and bind your UI to a collection of those new instances.

Comment: Well, no quite. The problem is the so called 'magic' number is associated with the column (each column should use a different number) and the Key property you suggest will be associated with a row...